# What tools are available to assess the security holes in my network, vulnerability assessment and penetration testing

Tags: vulnerability

I need to do some vulnerability assessment, security holes and penetration test in my network area (DC and DRC). Not only scanning about web, but all behind the IP address, private or public and any ports. anyway my questions is :
1.) what best free tools are available for this? 
2.) what best paid tools are available for this? 
3.) do you have any MOP or doc procedures how to do this?

Comment: I'm sorry but tool recommendations are off-topic here.

Comment: Kali is a linux distribution specifically prepared to the task you are asking about, it comes with the latest tools to do the job.